# Sorting multidimensional array by values alphanumerically (first numbers, then letters)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this $countries array:

```
Array ( [0] => 2013 Germany [1] => country [2] => Berlin [3] => Beer)
Array ( [0] => 2012 Italy [1] => country  [2] => Rome [3] => Wine  )
Array ( [0] => 2013 Germany [1] => country  [2] => Munich [3] => Beer )
Array ( [0] => 2013 Germany [1] => country  [2] => Dusseldorf [3] => Beer )
Array ( [0] => 2013 Italy [1] => country  [2] => Venice [3] => Wine )
Array ( [0] => 2013 Russia ....) etc
```

I would like is to sort it by ascending order of the year so I'd have something like

```
Array ( [0] => 2012 Italy [1] => country  [2] => Rome [3] => Wine  )
Array ( [0] => 2013 Germany [1] => country [2] => Berlin [3] => Beer)
Array ( [0] => 2013 Germany [1] => country  [2] => Munich [3] => Beer )....
```

I've tried *sort*, *asort* and *natsort* but none of them seem to work so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you missed the magical [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: asort should work, I have tired and working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($countries as $key => $row) {
    $year[$key]  = $row[0];
}


array_multisort($year, SORT_ASC, $countries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort multidimensional arrays by **array_multisort** function.

First you have to prepare sorting array then you apply sorting itself:

```
$sortArr = array();

// prepare the sorting array
foreach ($arrayToSort as $row) {
  $sortArr[] = $row[0];  // put there the year value
}

// sorting - first param is helper array, then constant with sorting direction, third param is array you wish to sort
array_multisort($sortArr, SORT_ASC, $arrayToSort);
```

Comment: Tried this, still getting them in the original order

Comment: What is your PHP version? It works for me in 5.3.21 but I'm pretty sure it works in a few minor versions back.

Comment: Using 5.3.23, I really can't understand how the ordering is working. I'm trying different constants in the 2nd part line DESC, NUMERIC etc and it's slightly changing however I never get to see 2012 on the first line.

Comment: The principle is as follows: the function sorts the first array (set of year values) in order defined by sorting type in second parameter (there are couple of constants for that, see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)). Meanwhile it sorts the array in the third argument in the **same order** as the first array is being sorted. As you can see _Ruben Serrate Pardo_ posted quite the same solution so this should work. Unfortunately I have no idea why this is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using usort. Look at example #2 in the documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
):

> Example #2 usort() example using multi-dimensional array
>
> ```
> <?php
> function cmp($a, $b)
> {
>     return strcmp($a["fruit"], $b["fruit"]);
> }
>
> $fruits[0]["fruit"] = "lemons";
> $fruits[1]["fruit"] = "apples";
> $fruits[2]["fruit"] = "grapes";
>
> usort($fruits, "cmp");
>
> while (list($key, $value) = each($fruits)) {
>     echo "\$fruits[$key]: " . $value["fruit"] . "\n";
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> When sorting a multi-dimensional array, $a and $b contain references
>   to the first index of the array. The above example will output:
>
> ```
> $fruits[0]: apples
> $fruits[1]: grapes
> $fruits[2]: lemons
> ```

Comment: I've tried using usort, I'm a php newbie, I got a bunch of warnings back, so I really don't think I used it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your array make it without key value as:

```
$test = array (Array (  '2013 Germany',  'country',  'Berlin ', 'Beer'),
Array (  '2012 Italy' , 'country'  , 'Rome',  'Wine'  ),
Array (  '2013 Germany' , 'country' ,  'Munich' ,  'Beer' ),
Array (  '2013 Germany',  'country' ,  'Dusseldorf',  'Beer' ),
Array (  '2013 Italy' , 'country' ,  'Venice' , 'Wine' )
);
```

After that I have use :

```
asort($test);
$test = array_values($test);    
print_r($test);
```

And out put was:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012 Italy
            [1] => country
            [2] => Rome
            [3] => Wine
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013 Germany
            [1] => country
            [2] => Berlin 
            [3] => Beer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013 Germany
            [1] => country
            [2] => Dusseldorf
            [3] => Beer
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013 Germany
            [1] => country
            [2] => Munich
            [3] => Beer
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013 Italy
            [1] => country
            [2] => Venice
            [3] => Wine
        )

)
```

Hope you are looking for this out put.